# 6hr 33 min to charge last 6% of battery - is this normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Exactly as asked - I couldn't figure out why exactly this is happening?

[image]

Comment: it is a calculated value, give it a moment to figure it out :)

Comment: is it normal? no it is not, but what is the health of your battery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is probably not normal.

You can hold the `alt` key and click on your battery icon.
Then click `Condition: X`.

What is your X? You can read some more information based on the window that popped up

By the way, does it really take 6.5 hour to charge to 100%? Cause it could just be some temporary mess-up with the estimation.

Comment: The health of my battery is Normal right now. It didn't end up taking 6+hrs to finish charging. That said, this issue has shown up more than once now. Should I be worried about it?

Comment: So it seems that it just reports longer times than it actually takes? It is a little bit weird but I guess you don't have to worry that much about it. How many cycles has your battery completed? (`system information` -> `Power`). You may also want to try this http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: It's at 244 cycles now. I hear it's usually about 300 cycles before the battery begins to deteriorate, is that correct?

Comment: It depends on the models. Unless you have a quite old one, it is about 1000. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585 If the problem occurs regularly you an check the link I added in the previous comment

Comment: Reinforces why I like Apple products. Well-designed and well-engineered. 1000 cycles on the Air.